# Url.Content throws exception when UrlRewrite module is installed and using ~(tilde) in passed parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewrite-module

The problem is:

1. I have installed `UrlRewrite` modole on my IIS for **"A"** website
2. I have **"B"** web site (MVC 5.0) which doesn't use 'UrlRewrite' module but get exception when calling `UrlHelper.Content("~/blobl/foo/bar")`. 
   The exception is because of using `UrlRewriter` module and using `~` character for function parameter at same time.
   The exception is:

   System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasThisRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)

If I uninstall `UrlRewrite` module, everything will be OK but the **"A"** website encounters problem. Also, I couldn't find any way to disable this module only for a website.

NOTE: I've checked [IIS URL Rewrite module: Url.Content() does not resolve CSS/Image path properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505776/iis-url-rewrite-module-url-content-does-not-resolve-css-image-path-properly) but I don't want to change the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I found there is no regular way to enable `UrlRewrite`module for a website without affecting other sites.
The simplest way is: 
removing this module from affected websites by the following line in `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <modules>
      <remove name="RewriteModule" />
   </modules>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more information, check this: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should add your **B** web site's URLs to ignore list of URL Rewrite.

Add the following in your web.config:

```
<rule name="Ignore URLs" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/blobl/foo/bar\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/blobl/foo/bar/gar\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know all B web sites' urls. Some urls are generated dynamically. Also It adds a UrlRewrite rule for a site that doesn't use this module. I think It would not be a good idea